# VSC Autocomplete imported styles for JSX files

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete

I am having problems with autocomplete of imported styles in JSX files.
Whenever i import styles from another files i dont get autocompletion.
Like i have a style in JS file:

```
  searchWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    marginRight: SIZES.small,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: SIZES.medium,
    height: "100%",
  },
```

and i am importing it to JSX file.
Yet i dont get autocompletion.

```
    <View styles={styles.searchContainer}>
        <View styles={styles.}>  //no autocompletion here

        </View>

      </View>
```

I am importing this file like so:

```
import styles from './welcome.style';
```

Code executes properly, but no autocompletion.
Also everything enabled:
Emmet file:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.largeFileOptimizations": false,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.ambiguousCharacters": false,
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
    "javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
    "emmet.preferences": {
        

    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",

    },
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "javascript": "jsx"
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.jsx": "javascriptreact"
    }
}
```